# Magnitude of roots of a quadratic function with complex coefficients

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

Suppose $c \in \mathbb C$ with $|c| < 1$. I constructed a quadratic function $t^2 - 2 c t + c = 0$. I want to know whether the magnitude of the roots are smaller than $1$. The answer for real $c$ is simple. If $c$ is real, then the roots are $c \pm \frac{\sqrt{4c^2 - 4c}}{2}$. Since $4c^2 - 4c < 0$, the second part is imaginary. So the magnitude will be $\sqrt{c^2 + \frac{4c-4c^2}{4}} = \sqrt{c} < 1$.

I got lost when considering $c$ is complex. Specifically, is the discriminant $4c^2 - 4c$ or $4|c|^2 - 4c$? How do we take the root of complex number?

Comment: Maybe this helps : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem

Comment: For the root of  a complex number. If $z=x+iy$, then the square roots have absolute value $v=(x^2+y^2)^{1/4}$ and the argument is $a=1/2\cdot \arctan(\frac{y}{x})$ (if $x\ne 0$ , if x=0, the argument is $a=\frac{\pi}{4}$). Then, the roots are $v\cdot(\cos(a)+i\cdot \sin(a))$ and $v\cdot (\cos(a+\pi)+i\cdot \sin(a+\pi))$

Comment: @Peter: Thanks. Is it possible to give a sufficient condition (on magnitude of $c$) such that the roots have magnitude smaller than $1$?

Comment: Rouche's theorem should give such conditions. See my link above.

Comment: "*If $c$ is real ... $4c^2 - 4c < 0$*" $\;$ That's only true if $\,c \in (0,1)\,$. For example, if $\,c = -1/2\,$ then $\,|c| \lt 1\,$ but the equation $\,t^2 + t - 1/2 = 0\,$ has a real root $\,-(1 + \sqrt{3})/2 \lt -1\,$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Too long for a comment*.)

The equation can be written as $\,(t-c)^2 = c^2-c\,$ then by the triangle inequality with $\lambda=|c| \lt 1\,$:

$$
|t-c|^2 = |c|\,|1-c| \le |c|(1+|c|) \quad\implies\quad |t| \le |t-c|+|c| \le \lambda + \sqrt{\lambda(1+\lambda)}
$$

Therefore $\,f(\lambda)=\lambda + \sqrt{\lambda(1+\lambda)}\,$ is an upper bound for the magnitude of roots $\,|t|\,$, but it does not insure that $\,|t| \le 1\,$ since $\,f(\lambda)\,$ can take values larger than $\,1\,$ e.g. $\,f(\lambda) \gt 1\,$ for $\,\forall \lambda \gt \frac{1}{3}\,$.

It also follows that $\,|c| \lt \frac{1}{3}\,$ is a sufficient condition for the roots to have magnitude less than $\,1\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ My answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4458171/291201) covers this as the case $\,\beta = \gamma = c\,$. The necessary and sufficient conditions for both roots to be inside the unit circle, according to $\,(8)\,$ in that post:

$$
2 \left(|c|^2 + |c^2 - c|\right) - 1 \;\lt\; |c|^2 \;\lt\; 1
$$

Here $\,|c| \lt 1\,$, so the second inequality is always satisfied. This leaves the condition:

$$
\begin{align}
2 \left(|c|^2 + |c^2 - c|\right) - 1 &\;\lt\; |c|^2 \quad\iff\quad  |c|^2 + 2\,|c^2 - c| \lt 1
\end{align}
$$

After straightforward algebraic manipulations, the condition reduces to:

$$
3\,|c|^4 + 2\, \big(3 - 4\,\text{Re}(c)\big)\,|c|^2  \lt 1
$$

For real $\,c\,$, the condition reduces to $\,3 c^4 - 8 c^3 + 6 c^2 - 1 \lt 0 \iff c \in \left(- \dfrac{1}{3}, \,1\right)\,$.

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.

Answer (score 0):

I found a counterexample : Let $c=0.7+0.6i$ , then $|c|<1$ , but the polynomial $t^2-2ct+c=0$ has a root with absolute value greater than $1$.