# necessary and sufficient condition for magnitude of roots of a quadratic equation less than 1 with complex coefficient

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

I have a general quadratic equation with complex coefficient

$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$

where a, b c are all complex numbers.

I wonder is there a necessary and sufficient condition to guarantee that all roots of this quadratic equation has magnitude less than 1?

Any sufficient condition would also be helpful.

Comment: Divide by $\,a \ne 0\,$ first, then see [Show the roots of the quadratic equation $z^2 +bz+ c = 0$ lie in or on the unit circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839654/show-the-roots-of-the-quadratic-equation-z2-bz-c-0-lie-in-or-on-the-unit).

Comment: Thanks, but here b and c are both complex, I thought that post only holds for real b and c?

Comment: Right, indeed. What would be relevant is [Schur stability regions for complex quadratic polynomials](https://eric.ed.gov/?id=EJ898640) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes $\,a \ne 0\,$, $\,c \ne 0\,$ since the other cases are trivial.

Let $\,\dfrac{b}{a} = - 2 \beta\,$, $\,\dfrac{c}{a}= \gamma\,$, then after dividing by $\,a\,$ the equation becomes $\,x^2 - 2 \beta x + \gamma = 0\,$, and the roots can be written as $\,x_{1,2} = \beta \pm \delta\,$ where $\,\delta^2 = \beta^2 - \gamma\,$ is the reduced discriminant.

The roots $\,\beta \pm \delta\,$ are the diagonals of the parallelogram with sides $\,\beta, \delta\,$. By the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law):

$$
|\beta-\delta|^2 + |\beta+\delta|^2 = 2\left(|\beta|^2 + |\delta|^2\right) \tag{1}
$$

Let $\,s \gt 0\,$ be the magnitude of one of the roots, then the magnitude of the other one is $\,\dfrac{|\gamma|}{s}\,$ by [Vieta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas). Substituting in $\,(1)\,$:

$$
s^2 + \frac{|\gamma|^2}{s^2} = 2\left(|\beta|^2 + |\delta|^2\right) \tag{2}
$$

It follows that $\,s\,$ is one of the positive roots of the biquadratic with real coefficients:

$$
s^4 - 2\left(|\beta|^2 + |\delta|^2\right) s^2 + |\gamma|^2 = 0 \tag{3}
$$

With $\,s^2 = t\,$, $\,|\beta|^2 + |\delta|^2 = u \gt 0\,$, $\,|\gamma|^2 = v \gt 0\,$, the equation is a real quadratic in $\,t\,$:

$$
t^2 - 2 u t + v = 0 \tag{4}
$$

For verification, the latter has two positive real roots (as expected), since their sum and product are both positive, and its reduced discriminant is non-negative:

$$
u^2 - v = \left(|\beta|^2 + |\delta|^2\right)^2 - |\gamma|^2 = \underbrace{\left(|\beta|^2 + |\delta|^2 - |\gamma|\right)}_{\ge\, 0\, \text{ since } \, |\gamma| \,\le\, |\beta|^2 + |\beta^2 - \gamma|\\ \text{by the triangle inequality}}\; \underbrace{\left(|\beta|^2 + |\delta|^2 + |\gamma|\right)}_{\gt \, 0} \;\ge\; 0 \tag{5}
$$

Finally, the roots $\,x_{1,2}\,$ are inside the unit circle iff the roots of $\,(4)\,$ are in $\,(0,1)\,$. Since the roots $\,u \pm \sqrt{u^2 - v}\,$ are known to be positive, the condition reduces to the larger one being less than $\,1\,$:

$$
u + \sqrt{u^2 - v} \,\lt\, 1 \tag{6}
$$

Equivalently:

- $u \lt 1 \tag{6.a}$
- $\require{cancel} u^2 - v \lt (1-u)^2 \;\;\iff\;\; \cancel{u^2} - v \lt 1 - 2 u + \cancel{u^2} \;\;\iff\;\; 2 u \lt 1 + v \tag{6.b}$

Since $\,v \le u^2\,$ by $\,(5)\,$ and $\,u \lt 1\,$ by $\,(6.a)\,$ it follows that $\,v \lt 1\,$, which just confirms that $\,|x_{1,2}| \lt 1\,$ $\,\implies |x_1x_2| = |\gamma| \lt 1\,$ $\,\implies v \lt 1\,$. Then $\,(6.a)+(6.b)\,$ can be coalesced into:

$$
2 u - 1 \;\lt\; v \;\lt\; 1 \tag{7}
$$

Or, reverting to the $\,\beta, \gamma\,$ variables:

$$
2 \left(|\beta|^2 + |\beta^2 - \gamma|\right) - 1 \;\lt\; |\gamma|^2 \;\lt\; 1 \tag{8}
$$

Or, reverting to the $\,a,b,c\,$ variables:

$$
|b|^2 + |b^2 - 4ac| - 2\,|a|^2 \;\lt\; 2\, |c|^2 \;\lt\; 2 \tag{9}
$$